# How to access angular 2 module from npm by its name

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have published an angular 2 library of my own into npm. It is giving me errors when I tried to access the module like this `import {MyModule} from 'my-module'` but it works like this 
`import {MyModule} from 'node_modules/my-module/my-module.module`. So my question is how to access it with the module name.

Comment: take a look here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#classic

Comment: that was helpful.

Comment: you are welcome, does it resolves your issue?

Comment: I didn't try it yet.but I hope it will.